# Getting Bluetooth access in Appcelerator titanium for IOS and ANDROID

Tags: bluetooth, appcelerator

I am trying to get the list of Bluetooth devices and check if a particular device is connected or not with titanium Appclerator. What is the best approach?

I have used the library https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-bluetooth/ but not sure how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at the provided API documentation? It's not in the index markdown at the root of the project, but rather here: https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-bluetooth/blob/master/documentation/index.md

I have not used the module but it seems to me like you would startScan with the CentralManager which I'm assuming returns a list of peripherals that you could then connect to.

Comment: I don't get it. I want to use it on android, but I can't see the part when it sends data. I can't find how to do it.